# Laravel API and CURL

Tags: php, laravel

I have created an API using Laravel 5. When I run a PHP curl request it is not working but if I run the API in AJAX it works or in Postman. There are no errors in the Laravel storage logs and there is no errors in the Apache2 logs.

Laravel controller:

```
public function getNo(){
    $NumArr = [];
    $number = testnumber::whereNull('ref')->limit(1)->value('stu');
    $NumArr[] = $number;
    if(!empty($number)){
        return response()->json($NumArr[0],201);
    }else{
        return response()->json("No Found",201);
    }
}
```

API result is:

```
479555
```

PHP file:

```
function getNumber(){
    $url = "https://example.com/v2/num";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Request'
    ]);
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    return $resp;
}
```

`echo getNo();`

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo getNumber();`. It should work.

And in my local environment, I changed `return $resp` to `echo $resp` and it works with php artisan command.

```
public function handle()
{
    $url = "https://example.com/v2/num";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Request'
    ]);
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $resp;  // echo curl content
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add This line

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```